# WiFiShield Sending NTP request packet but no response

Tags: c++, networking, udp, arduino, ntp

I'm trying to contact an NTP server sending a UDP packet using the WiFiShield to synchronize time on my Arduino Uno. I've spent hours reading different tutorials and forums but no success. Irrespective of my code the example from http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/UdpNTPClient is not working either. I get no response. After using wireshark I am not even sure if the Arduino even sends the packet.

What I tried:

- Using Arduino IDE 1.0.3 with the WiFi library of the IDE 1.0.5 (because WiFiUdp is not present in 1.0.3) or using Arduino IDE 1.0.5
- Upgrading the firmware of the WiFiShield using the firmware shipped with IDE 1.0.5. However, I could not check if it succeeded or what firmware version was installed before.
- Other examples like SimpleWebServerWiFi are working.
- Setting up an ntp server on my laptop in the same WiFi and contacting that server.
- Changing the target server checking http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi for availability
- Checking for packets sent/received by the Arduino using wireshark (local server) or wireshark + local arp spoofing to route the traffic through wireshark (public server) but in neither case I could detect any packet.
- Checking the [definition of the NTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905#section-7.3) but the packet creation looks fine.
- Increasing the waiting time for the response.

To calm you down I changed the code to not request the time every 10 seconds but it doesn't seem to send a request anyway...

Any tips?

Code from http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/UdpNTPClient:

```
/*

 Udp NTP Client
 
 Get the time from a Network Time Protocol (NTP) time server
 Demonstrates use of UDP sendPacket and ReceivePacket
 For more on NTP time servers and the messages needed to communicate with them,
 see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol
 
 created 4 Sep 2010
 by Michael Margolis
 modified 9 Apr 2012
 by Tom Igoe
 
 This code is in the public domain.
 
 */

#include <SPI.h>        
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
char ssid[] = "mynetwork";  //  your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "mypassword";       // your network password
int keyIndex = 0;            // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)

unsigned int localPort = 2390;      // local port to listen for UDP packets

IPAddress timeServer(129, 6, 15, 28); // time.nist.gov NTP server

const int NTP_PACKET_SIZE = 48; // NTP time stamp is in the first 48 bytes of the message

byte packetBuffer[ NTP_PACKET_SIZE]; //buffer to hold incoming and outgoing packets

// A UDP instance to let us send and receive packets over UDP
WiFiUDP Udp;

void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue:
    while(true);
  }


  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:    
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  printWifiStatus();

  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  Udp.begin(localPort);
}

void loop()
{
  sendNTPpacket(timeServer); // send an NTP packet to a time server
    // wait to see if a reply is available
  delay(1000);  
  Serial.println( Udp.parsePacket() );
  if ( Udp.parsePacket() ) {
    Serial.println("packet received");
    // We've received a packet, read the data from it
    Udp.read(packetBuffer,NTP_PACKET_SIZE);  // read the packet into the buffer

    //the timestamp starts at byte 40 of the received packet and is four bytes,
    // or two words, long. First, esxtract the two words:

    unsigned long highWord = word(packetBuffer[40], packetBuffer[41]);
    unsigned long lowWord = word(packetBuffer[42], packetBuffer[43]);  
    // combine the four bytes (two words) into a long integer
    // this is NTP time (seconds since Jan 1 1900):
    unsigned long secsSince1900 = highWord << 16 | lowWord;  
    Serial.print("Seconds since Jan 1 1900 = " );
    Serial.println(secsSince1900);              

    // now convert NTP time into everyday time:
    Serial.print("Unix time = ");
    // Unix time starts on Jan 1 1970. In seconds, that's 2208988800:
    const unsigned long seventyYears = 2208988800UL;    
    // subtract seventy years:
    unsigned long epoch = secsSince1900 - seventyYears;  
    // print Unix time:
    Serial.println(epoch);                              


    // print the hour, minute and second:
    Serial.print("The UTC time is ");       // UTC is the time at Greenwich Meridian (GMT)
    Serial.print((epoch  % 86400L) / 3600); // print the hour (86400 equals secs per day)
    Serial.print(':');  
    if ( ((epoch % 3600) / 60) < 10 ) {
      // In the first 10 minutes of each hour, we'll want a leading '0'
      Serial.print('0');
    }
    Serial.print((epoch  % 3600) / 60); // print the minute (3600 equals secs per minute)
    Serial.print(':');
    if ( (epoch % 60) < 10 ) {
      // In the first 10 seconds of each minute, we'll want a leading '0'
      Serial.print('0');
    }
    Serial.println(epoch %60); // print the second
  }
  // wait ten seconds before asking for the time again
  delay(10000);
}

// send an NTP request to the time server at the given address
unsigned long sendNTPpacket(IPAddress& address)
{
  //Serial.println("1");
  // set all bytes in the buffer to 0
  memset(packetBuffer, 0, NTP_PACKET_SIZE);
  // Initialize values needed to form NTP request
  // (see URL above for details on the packets)
  //Serial.println("2");
  packetBuffer[0] = 0b11100011;   // LI, Version, Mode
  packetBuffer[1] = 0;     // Stratum, or type of clock
  packetBuffer[2] = 6;     // Polling Interval
  packetBuffer[3] = 0xEC;  // Peer Clock Precision
  // 8 bytes of zero for Root Delay & Root Dispersion
  packetBuffer[12]  = 49;
  packetBuffer[13]  = 0x4E;
  packetBuffer[14]  = 49;
  packetBuffer[15]  = 52;
 
  //Serial.println("3");

  // all NTP fields have been given values, now
  // you can send a packet requesting a timestamp:         
  Udp.beginPacket(address, 123); //NTP requests are to port 123
  //Serial.println("4");
  Udp.write(packetBuffer,NTP_PACKET_SIZE);
  //Serial.println("5");
  Udp.endPacket();
  //Serial.println("6");
}


void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
memset(packetBuffer, 0, NTP_PACKET_SIZE);
packetBuffer[0] = 0b00011011; //  (0x1B) for NTPv3 
// or
// packetBuffer[0] = 0b00100011;` (0x23) for NTPv4
```

and don't modify the rest of the request structure to start with. NTP will respond to clients with this minimum request setup.

**Edit:**

`localPort = 2390` should this be the "ntp-port" (123)? or
even 8888 as described here: "[Network Time Protocol (NTP) Client](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial.UdpNtpClient)". **Note:** The link
looks very much the same as your link but it is NOT the same. The port is specified differently.

Does the code ever go beyond `setup()`.

```
...
// check for the presence of the shield:
if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
  Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
  // don't continue:
  while(true);
}
...
```

looks weird to me. "Don't continue" is implemented as a busy "stay here".

Comment: +1 thanks for the tip with the unnecessary structure modification. Tried this with both NTP versions and both IDE versions but it did not change anything :-(

Comment: No, the port is the outgoing UDP port of my client (on which it awaits the response too I think). I tried 8888 too. I had seen that link too. They are using the `Ethernet` library which is not suitable for the wireless connection I'm using. The request is sent to port 123 in the line `Udp.beginPacket(address, 123); //NTP requests are to port 123`. The code goes beyond `setup()`. I checked with various debug outputs to know where it goes. The problem is that I don't receive a response. The if-statement you mentioned only checks if the WiFiShield is connected to the Arduino main board.

Comment: The implemenation of "don't continue" is correct as all the Arduino does is repeat the contents of the `loop()` function as long as it has power.